livewire image upload problem on production
I'm facing an issue with image uploading and previewing using Livewire on both my local environment and my Hostinger-hosted site. When I try to upload images, the temporary URL for the preview (temporaryUrl()) doesn’t seem to work. Here's the error I’m seeing:
http://repair.test/livewire/upload-file?expires=1731506189&signature=78c90aededc3054b803e3cd1e5f339f32f36d42bf75faf121343a64b8d4680bc
<div class="mb-3">
    <label for="portfolioPictures" class="form-label">Portfolio Pictures</label>
    <div id="fileUploadContainer">
        <div class="file-upload-wrapper" id="fileUploadWrapper">
            <p>Please refer to the uploaded files below:</p>
            
            <!-- Input with Livewire directive -->
            <input type="file" id="portfolioPictures" wire:model="images"
                   name="portfolio_pictures[]" multiple accept="image/*">

            <!-- Error Handling -->
            @error('images.*') 
                <span class="error">{{ $message }}</span> 
            @enderror
        </div>

        <!-- Preview Section -->
        <div class="file-preview" id="filePreview" style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;">
            @if ($images)
                @foreach ($images as $index => $image)
                    <div style="position: relative; display: inline-block; margin-right: 10px;">
                        <img src="{{ $image->temporaryUrl() }}" alt="Portfolio Image"
                             class="rounded shadow" style="max-width: 100px;">
                             
                        <!-- Cross Button to Remove Image -->
                        <button type="button" wire:click="removeImage({{ $index }})"
                                style="position: absolute; top: -10px; right: 0; background: red; color: white; border: none; border-radius: 50%; width: 22px; height: 22px; cursor: pointer;">
                            &times;
                        </button>
                    </div>
                @endforeach
            @else
                <p>No portfolio images uploaded.</p>
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

